# Why aren't we using drone blimp/hybird airship for delivery?

Tags: commercial-aviation, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, airship

Currently, the heaviest weight a commercial drone (the type that delivers Amazon package, not the type that delivers tons of stuff) can [lift is 4.5kg](http://unmannedcargo.org/how-much-weight-can-delivery-drones-carry/) with [a 30-45 minute battery life](http://unmannedcargo.org/uav-equipped-delivery-trucks-dogs-worst-nightmare/). A drone blimp/hybird airship might be bigger and slower, but it would take less energy--the lift is generated by the balloon or some lifting surface instead of the propellers. Since the Boeing 747 win against the Concorde because it can carry more people with a cheaper price despite much slower than Concorde, why aren't we using a drone blimp/hybird airship to deliver Amazon packages instead?

Comment: Delivery of what? You're going to have a blimp deliver Amazon packages?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking about Amazon packages or even Uber Eats

Comment: What size is this drone blimp? And, where will it land? How will you get the package from the drone blimp to behind the concrete pillar at my front door? Are you planning on airdropping a package into my backyard? What about pools? Am I going to have to install some sort of package receptacle or landing pad? Who is paying for that? Will it go with my landscaping? What about the nearby high tension power transmission lines? How will that work with the 400’ altitude limit? What about the line-of-sight rules for Part 107? Will they be able to operate above people walking by on the sidewalk?

Comment: How much wind can your blimps (or FTM your drones) handle?  Hereabouts, in some seasons 30-40 mph or more is a normal afternoon breeze: http://www.twainquotes.com/Zephyr.html  A good winter storm can bring much higher winds, enough to flip semi trailers.

Comment: @user39178 you should precise in the description the kind of packages you want to deliver. pizza delivering (constrained by time, your pizza has to be delivered less than half an hour after its baking and hardly weight the 4.5km limit of your example) is not the same as books, clothes or electronic material (weight, density, cargo value). Remember that the 747 was a good choice for hub-and-spoke model, hardly what a food deliver drone network would look like.

Comment: Also it might looks like a dupe, I think this question can be slightly transformed to avoid being a dupe. The market is clearly not the same. It is about small legs delivery (from the warehouse, the airport or a restaurant to any point in the same city, typical deliveroo's market) whereas the potential dupe address longer legs, from airport to airport or from airport to huge industrial site.

Comment: @Manu H: Also, a lot of package delivery isn't within cities, it's from delivery company's freight terminal to some suburban or rural location that's many miles/km distant.  It would be highly inefficient to send out drones/blimps carrying one package at a time, instead of a truck that drives a route to deliver all packages.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why that will probably not happen.

Number 1: As of right now drones/blimps are very big for 1 package. It is *much* more efficient to use a car that can take in hundreds of packages.

Number 2: There are may types of drones/blimps that can be flammable exposed to certain chemicals. Also... where is the drone going to fly? In airspace where planes are? Where is it going to land? What about apartment buildings?

That's why this is not plausible. Maybe one day it will be.